# Stop closing modal when pressing outside modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make a popup modal where I don't want to be able to close the modal by clicking outside the modal window. I've searched and tried different solutions with backdrop but nothing seems to work. Would appreciate any help! The code I have for the modal is:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <transition name="modal">
      <div v-if="isOpen">
        <div class="overlay" @click.self="isOpen = false;">
          <div class="modal">
            <h1>Modal heading</h1>
            <p>This my first modal using vue.js</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
    <button @click="isOpen = !isOpen;">
      {{ isOpen ? "Close" : "Open" }} modal
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Does the `overlay` div constitute the modal background? If so, shouldn't the click handler be on the `modal` div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @click event is placed on the overlay, which I presume is positioned behind the modal. This part closes the modal when clicking on the overlay layer.

```
@click.self="isOpen = false;"
```

Just remove the code above. You can place it on another component; like a closing cross, button, or trigger the closing in any way you want.